# how to install OpenSSH Server windows 11 OFFINE, without internet connection with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, openssh, windows-11

I need to isntall SSH server on windows 11 using powershell. It should be a script that isntalls SSH server and logs you in and does everything untill this: `ssh domain\username@servername`

These are some methods I tried but unsuccessfully: (offline ofc)
https://it-infra-ya.com/en/ws19-sshserver_en/#toc2
from github, with .msi file (this works but I need to strat the script from server offline and this method doesnt work for me..)
I tried to do that by downloading file "OpenSSH-Client-Package_31bf3856ad364e35_amd64__" from https://www.exefiles.com/en/cab/openssh-client-package-31bf3856ad364e35-amd64-cab/ and using this command : `PS C:\Windows\system32> DISM /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\Users\krivosik\Desktop\Scripts\scripts\OpenSSH-Client-Package_31bf3856ad364e35_amd64__.cab`
I read that the "Online" part doesnt really mean online so it should work but it does not work for me..
I dont have that ISO file where the .cab file should be located so i cant really work with this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-v2--capabilities?view=windows-11.

Can anyone help how to do it the way i need to? thanks.
The best way would be to work with that .cab file but ill take anything :D

Comment: DISM online doesn't mean that it has Internet connectivty. It means it will apply changes to running OS, and not to an installation image. Anyway, questions about how to install software are better on-topic at SuperUser or ServerFault.